# Creation of my-app using create-react-app fails with below errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to create my-app using create-react-app. Below error is seen

create-react-app my-app

> Creating a new React app in C:\Users\racrk\React\my-app.
>
> Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
>   Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...
>
> core-js@2.6.9 postinstall C:\Users\racrk\React\my-app\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
>   node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
>
> npm ERR! file C:\Program Files\git\bin\bash.exe
>
> npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\git\bin\bash.exe
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno ENOENT
>
> npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Program Files\git\bin\bash.exe
>
> npm ERR! core-js@2.6.9 postinstall: node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
>
> npm ERR! spawn C:\Program Files\git\bin\bash.exe ENOENT
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the core-js@2.6.9 postinstall script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\racrk\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-09-25T07_06_05_990Z-debug.log
>
> Aborting installation.
>     npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Answer (score 2):

npm don't like the space in `C:\Program Files\git\bin\bash.exe` when he try to spawn `bash`

try to change the location of `bash.exe` in a path without space

don't forget to update your `PATH` env

Answer (score 1):

Make sure a bash executable actually exists at the path output by npm. You can update the path that npm uses for the script shell using:

`npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"`

or check your current script-shell with:

`npm config get script-shell`

You can read more [here](https://medium.com/@dSebastien/fixing-bash-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-when-used-within-npm-scripts-on-61614391e417)